# Python: operand error when I try to run functions for finding the sum and mean

Tags: python, list, loops, sum, typeerror

I'm a Python beginner and I have a task in which I need to create my own functions to find the sum and mean of a list. I tried making the following formulas:

```
import math

list1 = ['ABC123', 0.00095, 0.00081, 0.0023, 0.00209, 0.0017, 0.00215, 0.00167, 0.00164, 0.00206, 0.00233, 0.00239, 0.00242, 0.0023, 9e-05, 0.00177, 0.001]

def samplesum(my_list):
    '''Finds the sum of a list'''
    total_sum = 0
    for element in my_list:
        total_sum += element
    return total_sum


def samplemean(my_list):
    """Finds the mean of a list"""
    sum_of_num = sum(my_list)
    list_mean = sum_of_num / len(my_list)
    return list_mean

samplesum(list1)
samplemean(list1)
```

When I run the script, I get this error message:

```
File "Task.py", line 136, in <module>
    samplesum(list1)
File "Task.py", line 120, in samplesum
    total_sum += element
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

or if I mute out the `samplesum(my_list)` function using `#` I'll get this error for `samplemean(my_list)`

```
File "Task.py", line 137, in <module>
    samplemean(list1)
File "Task.py", line 125, in samplemean
    sum_of_num = sum(my_list)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: As several comments pointed out, it turns out I had a single string in that list in addition to the integers. I removed it by redefining the list without the string, but I think that's considered hard-coding and the assignment instructions don't allow hard-coding. How can I make Python ignore strings from the list using these formulas?

Comment: Looks like `list1` has at least one element which is a string. How is `list1` created?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  Specifically, your posted code does not reproduce the problem, since your code dies on the first executable line.

Comment: @biocoder Can you post the content of list1?

Comment: @Lucas Oh that was the issue! I forgot I had inserted a string header into list1. Thanks, I'll update my question

Comment: @Prune The issue here is that list1 has randomly generated integers, but the string is inserted manually. I can post an example in my question if that helps.

Comment: 'ABC123' is not an number. Remove it and your code will work.

Comment: Yes, it does help.  I've rescinded my closure vote.

Comment: Is the non-numeric entry always in the leading position?  If so, just operate on **mylist[1:]** instead of **mylist**.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Based your question update, you can achieve it by:

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3,"4", "str"]
>>> [int(x) for x in mylist if str(x).isdigit()]  ------> ONE
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [int(x) for x in mylist if isinstance(x, int) ]    ------>TWO
[1, 2, 3]
```

For example ONE: 
removes string `str` but keeps and converts numerical string `"4"` to interger 4.

For example TWO: keeps all integers only

**Original:**

Python doesn't support addition between **numerical string** and integer, you have to convert all **numerical string** to integer and then add them up

Convert all elements of your `mylist` to int:

```
mylist = [int(v) for v in mylist]
```

Or you can convert them all before pass `list1` to your `samplesum()` and `samplemean`

```
list1 = [int(v) for v in list1]
```

Then

```
for element in mylist:
    total_sum += element
```

Comment: It turns out I had a single string in that list. I removed it by redefining the list without it, but I think that's considered hard-coding and the assignment instructions discourage hard-coding. Is what you're showing me the way to make Python ignore strings from the list? Or how would you do that?

Comment: I thought you had numerical string in your list. for instance `"1" +1` will throw the type error. That's why I mentioned convert `numerical string` to integer other than convert string to integer. Glad you solved your issue

Comment: Please see my updated question to see the list I was using. Do you know how to make the function skip over the string so I don't have to redefine the list?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the updated question, you could think of the problem as:

- ignore strings
- only consider numbers

Those would be the two options:

```
# only consider numbers
list1 = [x for x in list1 if isinstance(x, (int, float, long))]

# ignore strings
list1 = [x for x in list1 if not isinstance(x, basestring)]
```